# Why is AJAX only replacing my variable in some places?

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following AJAX code, which replaces anything with class "percentreplacer" with the data in the "Percent" column of the MYSQL database:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#functionsquestionform2').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({  
            url :  "aplaygroundajaxtest.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
$(".percentreplace").text(data.percent); 
            },
            });
        });
});
</script>
```

In another part of my script, I have this snippet of PHP code:

```
 <?php echo '<span class="percentreplace">'.$data['FunctionsPercent'].'</span>'; ?>
```

When I run the code, the AJAX code at the top successfully replaces the above span with the percent value stored in the database (such as "6").

Later on in my code, I try to set this percent as a variable with the JQuery script shown below:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){    
var carouselbutton1percentage='<?php echo '<span class="percentreplace">'.$data['FunctionsPercent'].'</span>'; ?>' ....[cont'd]
```

Here, however, instead of replacing the entire PHP snippet with the percent (let's say 6), it sets the variable `carouselbutton1percentage` equal to `<span class="percentreplace">6</span>` I want the  tags to get stripped here just like they did in the former. I'm guessing this has something to do with the quotes, but I've played around with it quite a bit and I can't figure out what to change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: The variable is set to the HTML because that's how you wrote the code. Just remove the span tags from the second example.

Comment: ...but then AJAX won't update the variable when my form is submitted

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: @lumio Yep, at that line with the span in the Jquery I have an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" error

Comment: Look at the javascript generated by your PHP by using the view source function in your browser and see whether it's what you want.

Comment: @NieDzejkob It's generating: `var carouselbutton1percentage='<span class="percentreplace">8</span>'` rather than `var carouselbutton1percentage=8`

Comment: @Snoops because you wrote `<?php echo '<span...`

Comment: `var carouselbutton1percentage=<?php echo $data['FunctionsPercent']; ?>` - **Warning:** XSS vulnerable!

Comment: @lumio That won't update the variable until the page is refreshed, though. I'm trying to use the AJAX code to have this variable update as soon as the form is submitted without page refresh.

Comment: @niedzejkob How would I modify that, though? I have `<?php echo '<span class="percentreplace">'.$data['FunctionsPercent'].'</span>'; ?>` at the top of my code and that successfully returns a simple `8`. When I try to store that exact same code as a variable, however, the `span` tags remain. How do I tweak this so that only "8" gets stored as the variable and without the `span` tags?

Comment: Does it update when you submit the form?

Comment: @lumio Yes, pursuant to my comment above,  I have <?php echo '<span class="percentreplace">'.$data['FunctionsPercent'].'</span>'‌​; ?> at the top of my code and that successfully returns a simple 8. (The form submits, the database updates, and the AJAX code replaces everything with the current percentage value.) When I try to store that exact same code as a variable, however, the span tags remain.

Comment: What do you get when you add `console.log(data.percent)` in your AJAX success callback? (If you don't know how to check your console then write `alert(data.percent)`

Comment: @Snoops it returns a simple 8 because you strip the tags with `.text`.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Yes, but I want the tags to strip when I store it as a variable, too. Why doesn't it strip the tags here: `var carouselbutton1percentage='<?php echo '<span class="percentreplace">'.$data['FunctionsPercent'].'</span>'‌​; ?>'`

Comment: @lumio It returns 8

Comment: @Snoops Just don't print the <span> tags, the behavior for the first example won't change, but the second one will start working.

Comment: @NieDzejkob but if the second one doesn't have the <span> tags, the AJAX code won't update that variable as soon as the form is submitted. Those <span> tags contain the class that AJAX is immediately replacing upon form submit.

Comment: @Snoops No, the class it's replacing is defined in `$(".percentreplace").text(data.percent);`. Just try it.

Comment: @NieDzejkob I'm probably misunderstanding you and I apologize, but if I change `var carouselbutton1percentage='<?php echo '<span class="percentreplace">'.$data['FunctionsPercent'].'</span>'‌​; ?>'` to `var carouselbutton1percentage='<?php echo $data['FunctionsPercent']; ?>'` there is no longer anything with the class `percentreplace` so AJAX won't update this variable.

Comment: @Snoops did you try it or are you speculating on what the result will be?

Comment: @NieDzejkob I've tried it. That's what I originally had but the variable wouldn't update until I refreshed the page, which is why I tried using AJAX. I want the variable to update immediately upon form submit without page refresh.

Comment: @Snoops where is carouselbutton1percentage used?

Comment: @NieDzejkob I use it to change the percentage of a div that's shaded.

Comment: @Snoops show the full code, then

Comment: @NieDzejkob I'm not sure what the most efficient way to relay a full code is, but here it is in a JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bdxa48kr/

Comment: @Snoops create a [mcve], please

Comment: @NieDzejkob To be honest, I don't know exactly what that means. If you look at the answer provided below regarding escaping the quotes, do you think that would work? I think he's got the right idea, but when I copy exactly what he wrote there it returns a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @Snoops that's why it's blue - it's a LINK! I wonder what it leads to...

Comment: @NieDzejkob It did not register that you provided a link; there's lots of blue on the page at the moment and I'm flipping back and forth between tabs as I respond to people. I did not notice the hyperlink.

Comment: @Snoops Even if, if you don't know what something means, google it!

Comment: @NieDzejkob  I loosely knew what you meant that I knew that it wasn't going to help because you would be left with the code that I included in this original post; it would just be in one window. Besides the script wouldn't run because it wouldn't connect with any of the external files that I reference. Lastly, it seems like Louisik1 has already come across the solution (the need to escape the quotes); his suggestion is just a bit off so I'm working on modifying that now.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something.  But instead of storing a string 'that contains characters that look like PHP and jquery', I would think you want to actually update that html element, like you do in the AJAX response block.  So..

$(".percentreplace").text('6');

or

var carouselbutton1percentage = 6;

$(".percentreplace").text(carouselbutton1percentage);

But again, maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks for your response @louisik1. The problem is that I don't always want the percent to be 6. I want AJAX to replace anything with `class = percentreplace` with the value stored in the "percent" column of my database.

Comment: .... server response = x....

var y = x.toFixed(2) + '%';
$('.percentreplace').text(y);

like that?

Comment: I'm not sure, @louisik1 ; that looks completely different from anything I have ha. To perhaps better phrase my question: when I put `<?php echo '<span class="percentreplace">'.$data['FunctionsPercent'].'</span>'‌​‌​; ?>` at the head of my code, it returns a simple `8`. When I take that exact same code and store it as a variable: `var carouselbutton1percentage='<?php echo '<span class="percentreplace">'.$data['FunctionsPercent'].'</span>'; ?>'` it returns `var carouselbutton1percentage='<span class="percentreplace">8</span>'`  The `span` tags remain in the latter but not in the former.

Comment: Ahhh, I believe you need to escape the single quotes in your string.

Comment: Thanks, @louisik1. I figured it has something do with quotes. Please excuse my ignorance, but how would i escape the single quotes? can you show me how I would modify `var carouselbutton1percentage='<?php echo '<span class="percentreplace">'.$data['FunctionsPercent'].'</span>'‌​; ?>'`?

Comment: See my other answer. Cheers

Comment: It's returning a 500 error. Do you think I need to use ` echo strip_tags`? I'm playing around with that now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape your string properly?

```
var carouselbutton1percentage='<?php echo \'<span class="percentreplace">\'.$data[\'FunctionsPercent\'].\'</span>\'‌​; ?>';
```

Comment: I'm guessing that this is the right track, but it's now giving me a 500 (Internal Server Error)`